# Parallel.For "Thread local state"

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel.for

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460703%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

My question is: The third parameter in the parallel.for, what does it do?

When I change it to ()=> 1d, it doubles my result, set to two it triples, but it ignores the decimals.

Why does it ignore the decimals, if it was some sort of doubling? What is really happening there?

I've now tried adding locks. And it does not just initialize the interimresult to the value specified.

Here is the code Im using:

```
 static void RunParallelForCorrectedAdam()
{
    object _lock = new object();
    double result = 0d;
    //   Here we call same method several times.
    // for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)

    Parallel.For(0, 32,
        //      Func<TLocal> localInit,
    () => 3d,
        //      Func<int, ParallelLoopState, TLocal, TLocal> body,
        (i, state, interimResult) =>
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                return interimResult + 1;
            }

        },
        //Final step after the calculations
        //we add the result to the final result
        //   Action<TLocal> localFinally

        (lastInterimResult) =>
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                result += lastInterimResult;
            }
        }
    );
    //  Print the result
    Console.WriteLine("The result is {0}", result);
}
```

Comment: From the link you gave, it explains exactly what that 0d does.

Comment: But it does. If you initialise the variable to return with 3, it with give you a result of 3+ your result ..

Comment: I thought you didnt want to help me. I apologize. Ive updated the code now. If I change it to 1, it gives me 34-36 as a result. if I change it to 2, it gives me 34-40. If I change it to 3, it gives me about 34-50. What is this? And if I just leave it at 0d, it will give me 32 as a result.

Comment: The real problem with your code is `(lastInterimResult) => result += lastInterimResult`. Here you're concurrently accessing `result`. You need to use a `lock` here.

Comment: If I run your code, I always get 32 with 0d as the first part of the 3rd parameter. If I run it with 1d, it is always 33.. 2d gives 34 eg, it starts with the value I give it, and adds 1 for each itteration. As Henrik has pointed out, result is not locked for update although I wouldnt expect multiple +1s for any itteration.

Comment: Like this? (lastInterimResult) => {lock (_lock){result += lastInterimResult; } }
        );

Comment: @MakerOfTheUnicake yes

Comment: It still gives me different results and seemingly exponential results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `() => 3d`, `result` will be `32 + 3 * t`, where `t` is the number of threads that were used. `3d` is passed as `interimResult` to the first call to `body` within each thread.

The whole purpose of `Parallel.For` is to distribute the work on several threads. So `interimResult + 1` is executed exactly 32 times (possibly on different threads). But each thread has to have some initial value for `interimResult`. That's the value that is returned by `localInit`.

So if the work is distributed on e.g. two threds, each one does `+ 1` 16 times and thus calculates `3 + 16`. At the end, the partial results are summed yielding `6 + 32`.

In short, in this example, it doesn't make much sense for `localInit` to return somthing different than `0d`.

Comment: Yes this is true. Ive confirmed this now. This is the closest thing explaining what im seeing. Why will it be a multiplication of threads? Where does this thread multiplication happen?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: The third parameter in the parallel.for, what does it do?

It's a Func that gets executed once per thread. If your loop requires thread-local variable, this is where you initialize it.

EDIT:

Step by step:

```
(i, state, interimResult) => interimResult + 1,
```

Do you understand that `interimResult` is your local variable, the same one you initialized as 0d?

Comment: This does not explain its behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! No I do not understand that it is that. I cant get it to behave like that.

Comment: @MakerOfTheUnicake `interimResult ` is your local variable, and in each iteration you increment it by 1.